# nodejs dynamically create page

Tags: node.js

Hello！I want to dynamically create page in nodejs.I let it automatically generates ejs file and add router by fs.appendFile().But the new page can't run unless I restart the server.How can I do?Thanks!(I use express,ejs and mongoose)

Comment: So, why youre not use `res.render(..path_to_ejs_file)`

Comment: Perhaps , you should use nodemon to have always an automatic restart when it detect that a change has occured